# What is the use of "filename+CoreDataProperties.swift" and "filename.swift" NSmanagedObject subclasses?

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I recently noticed while creating the NSManagedObject subclass two classes are getting created. 
One is filename+CoreDataProperties.swift and other is filename.swift.
Is filename+CoreDataProperties.swift similar to filename.h  and  filename.swift to filename.m in Objective-c? If so then i can put my implement my logic inside the filename.swift using the +CoreDataProperties.swift class.

I seriously couldnt find out the differences between two these files and whats their use?
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5):

I think the `filename+CoreDataProperties.swift` version gets overwritten every time you export your model from `Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass` (e.g., every time you update your model and need to re-export the class files).

If you have some other, non-Core Data properties (or methods) in your custom subclass, they would be lost every time.

By separating the Core Data-specific code and your custom code, you can export from the Core Data editor as many times as you want without losing your non-Core Data additions.